# Bought eBay Galaxy Tab 4, Has SureMDM Nix Installed, Won't let me wipe

Tags: applications

So I purchased a Galaxy Tab 4 off eBay, and it has SureMDM Nix installed, and will not allow me to do anything with the device. I do not have access to the home page, google search, airplane mode, nothing to bypass this MDM.

I can't even plug the device into my computer as USB Debug Mode isn't enabled and I can't use the ADB commands either. I'm at a loss.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: If you connect it to a hotspot which needs a captive portal, will it open a browser?

Comment: Are you able to enter download mode: https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-t230-galaxy-tab-4-70/download-mode/